# Does Arduino support embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: support, formatting, markdown

[Over on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462), I am attempting to compile a complete list of Stack Exchange sites which support YouTube embedding.

Searching on Arduino Meta, I was unable to find any discussion of whether embedded YouTube videos are supported. Because [YouTube embedding is not shown in the markdown preview window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299082/display-embedded-youtube-videos-in-markdown-preview), there's no way to test without posting publically.

**Are embedded YouTube videos supported on Arduino?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one way to find out.

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>

Comment: What, no RickRoll?